# jQuery ui sortable: items option hash selection not being selective after changes in DOM element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I only want to make "li"s without class "ui-state-disabled" to be sortable in the code you can find on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oru9yz6r/1/).

```
$("#sortable-1, #sortable-2").sortable({
    items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    connectWith: ".connect"
});
```

I also added event listeners to the "ul"s so when the user double clicks on any "li", the user can disable/enable the sortable feature. I can make a disabled "li" to be sortable again by clicking on it, but I cannot re-disable it by adding class "ui-state-disabled" back to the "li".

I also noticed jQuery UI library automatically adds class "ui-sortable-handle" to "li"s that are sortable, but the re-enabled (by double clicking) "li"s are still sortable without class "ui-sortable-handle".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

missing the direct child selector.

## [Codepen](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/ed396d9cbaf22cec8e6e39f192ba02ce)

[image: tabbing]

## detail

You just need to add a tabindex attribute to the lis themselves.

html

```
<div>
    <ul id="sortable-1" class="connect">
        <li tabindex="0">Enabled</li>
        <li tabindex="0" >Enabled</li>
        <li tabindex="0">Enabled</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div>
    <ul id="sortable-2" class="connect">
        <li tabindex="0">Enabled</li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled" tabindex="0">Disabled</li>
        <li class="ui-state-disabled" tabindex="0">Disabled</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

## edit

## [DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/oru9yz6r/31/)

this is simple and does everything you want.

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortable-1, #sortable-2").sortable({
        items: "li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
        cancel: ".ui-state-disabled",
        connectWith: ".connect"
    });

    $("ul").on("dblclick", "li", function (event) {
        var $el = $(this);
        if ($el.text() == "Enabled") {
            $el.text("Disabled");
        } else {
            $el.text("Enabled");
        }
        $el.toggleClass("ui-state-disabled");
    })
})
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oru9yz6r/2/)

```
$("#sortable-1, #sortable-2").sortable({
    items: "> li:not(.ui-state-disabled)",
    connectWith: ".connect"
});
```

Comment: Thanks Todd for your quick answer, but I still could not disable the sortable feature on "Enabled" "li"s by double clicking on them. I want it so that double clicking a "li" can enable/disable the sortable function. Thanks again

Comment: Sorry for not being precise on what I want in the question, I want an alternative solution to solve it without using the jQuery key **cancel**. I have actually used cancel in the beginning, but it stops allowing user to tab into the "li"s when I used that option.